# Diff to full instructions

Tags: python, text, diff

Scratching my head as to where to start with this..

Say I have a diff between to XML documents - I want to be able to create a set of human readable commands to describe that diff.. The ultimate state is something like this [Amendment Bill - read from page 2 item 4](https://www.parliament.wa.gov.au/Parliament/Bills.nsf/E7CAF4F76C9871814825883E000EB8F9/$File/Bill%2B069-1.pdf)

eg (using HTML).
A

```
<body>
<h1>text</h1>
<p>It was the best of times</p>
</body>
```

B

```
<body>
<h1>text</h1>
<p>It was the worst of times</p>
</body>
```

Desired result

```
"Change the line following the Heading 'text' from 'It was the best of times' to 'It was the worst of times"
```